# Tween Arc outerRadius()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code, when you click on an arc of a circle, it tweens the outer radius of that particular arc of the circle.

```
var data = {
    "details": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "AAA", "pcArray": [25,75], "type": "c", "subtype": "p", },
        { "id": 2, "name": "BBB", "pcArray": [25,175], "type": "c", "subtype": "r", },
        { "id": 3, "name": "CCC", "pcArray": [5,95], "type": "e", "subtype": "p", },
        { "id": 4, "name": "DDD", "pcArray": [10,30], "type": "e", "subtype": "r", },
        { "id": 5, "name": "EEE", "pcArray": [0,30], "type": "c", "subtype": "r", },
    ],
};

var radius = 70, margin = 50,
        width = 2 * radius + margin,
        height = data.details.length * (2 * radius + margin) + margin;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 5)
    .innerRadius(radius / 2);

var arcLarge = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius + margin/2 - 5)
    .innerRadius(radius / 2);

var pie = d3.layout.pie();

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("background", "lightgray")
        .style("border", "3px solid #eee")
    .append("g");

var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(data.details)
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + (radius + 25) + "," + (i * (2 * radius + margin) + radius + margin) + ")"; })
        .attr("class", "slice");

var toggleArc = function(p){
    p.state = !p.state;
    var dest = p.state ? arcLarge : arc;

    d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("d", dest);
};

var arcs_path = arcs.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(function (d) { return pie(d.pcArray); })
    .enter().append("g")
    .on( "click", toggleArc );

arcs_path.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(g, i) {
      if (!i) return "white";
      var d = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).datum(),
          colorList = d3.scale.category10().range();

      if (d.type === "c") {
        if (d.subtype === "p") return colorList[0];
        if (d.subtype === "r") return colorList[1];
      }
      else if (d.type === "e") {
        if (d.subtype === "p") return colorList[2];
        if (d.subtype === "r") return colorList[3];
      }        
    });
```

How do I modify this code so that all arcs of a circle tween their outer radius no matter where I click on that particular circle?

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcd8yfa2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `toggleArc` for just the arc that is being clicked on, call it for all of them:

```
.on( "click", function() { arcs_path.each(toggleArc); } );
```

Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kcd8yfa2/1/).

If you want to highlight all arcs only for the particular pie chart being clicked on, select only the `g` elements for those:

```
.on( "click", function() { d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll("g").each(toggleArc); } );
```

Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kcd8yfa2/2/).

Comment: not for all the arcs in the data. just for the one clicked on.

Comment: Ah ok, that wasn't clear to me -- I've updated the answer.